# How to parse strings representing xml.dom.minidom nodes in python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a collection of nodes xml.dom.Node objects created using xml.dom.minidom. I store them (individually) in a database by converting them to a string using the toxml() method of a the Node object.

The problem is that I'd sometimes like to be able to convert them back to the appropriate Node object using a parser of some kind. As far as I can see the various libraries shipped with python use Expat which won't parse a string like '' or indeed anything which is not a correct xml string.

So, does anyone have any ideas? I realise I could pickle the nodes in some way and then unpickle them, but that feels unpleasant and I'd much rather be storing in a form I can read for maintenance purposes. Surely there is something that will do this?

In response to the doubt expressed that this is possible, an example of what I mean:

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> x=xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<a>foo<b>thing</b></a>')
>>> x.documentElement.childNodes[0]
<DOM Text node "u'foo'">
>>> x.documentElement.childNodes[0].toxml()
u'foo'
>>> xml.dom.minidom.parseString(x.documentElement.childNodes[0].toxml())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1928, in parseString
    return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
return builder.parseString(string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
parser.Parse(string, True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

In other words the ".toxml()" method does not create something that Expat (and hence out of the box parseString) will parse.

What I would like is something that will parse u'foo' into a text node. I.e. something that will reverse the effect of .toxml()

Comment: i don't see how a call to `toxml()` might generate an incorrect XML fragment... thus all string generated by `toxml()` should be parseable by the `parse()` or `parseString()` functions of `xml.dom.minidom`...

Comment: thank you for the example. indeed a text node is rendered as plain text, which is not valid xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What types of node do you need to store?

Obviously Element nodes should just work if serialised with `.toxml('utf-8')`; the results should be parseable as an XML document as-is and the element retrievable from `documentElement`, as long as there are no EntityReferences inside it that would need definition in the doctype.

Text nodes, on the other hand, would need either HTML-decoding or some wrapping to parse. If you only needed elements and text nodes you could guess whether it was an element from the first character, since that must always be `<` for an element:

```
var xml= node.toxml('utf-8')

...

if (xml.startswith('<')):
    node= minidom.parseString(xml).documentElement
else:
    node= minidom.parseString('<x>%s</x>'%xml).documentElement.firstChild
```

Comment nodes could similarly be stored by checking for `<!--`.

Other node types like Attr would be more work since their XML representation is not easily distinguishable from Text. You would probably need to store an out-of-band `nodeType` value to remember it. OTOH minidom doesn't implement `toxml()` on Attr anyway so maybe that's not an issue.

Comment: Its scraped data that I'm storing, so I was trying to be conservative about any assumptions I made, but you are probably right that its only going to be Elements and Text nodes that I have to worry about. Attr won't be an issue but its just possible there will be some comments. It would have been neat if there was just an easy parser out there that could accept strings, but storing an out of band note of the type is probably good enough. Just another column in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

try:
  node = parseString('') 
except Exception:
  node = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **`<![CDATA[xxx]]>`** wrap your content.

In your code, you can add this tag before parse.

```
'<![CDATA[<a>foo<b>thing</b></a>]]>'
```